# Best way to endian swap many structures in C++

Tags: c++, struct, swap

I have a lot of C++ struct that look kind of like this:

```
typedef struct {
    UINT32 foo    : 5;
    UINT32 spare0 : 27;
    double bar;
}  data;
```

or this

```
typedef struct {
    double foo;
    double bar;
} data2;
```

I'm currently endian swapping all structures by each field individually in a single function call, but I was wondering if there was some more efficient way of doing this without manually swapping each individual field for each struct.

Would the only way to do this is to create a function that requires the size for each field so the function would know how many bits to swap? Other methods are welcome as well.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no better way than what you are doing.  Even better would be to not write code that requires "endian swap" in the first place.

Comment: Although sometimes you can't avoid it, especially when communicating with peripheral devices, such as the usb coffee-pot-warmer via HTCPCP for example...

Comment: @M.M I agree we should try to avoid it as much as possible, but the reason i need to do a lot of these swapping is because I'm sending these struct to another device that is a different endian.